# Can't get Auth0 integration working with feathers

Tags: feathersjs

I'm having a hard time getting Auth0 integration working. I'm getting the response shown below

```js
{
    "name": "NotAuthenticated",
    "message": "error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line",
    "code": 401,
    "className": "not-authenticated",
    "data": {
        "library": "PEM routines",
        "function": "get_name",
        "reason": "no start line",
        "code": "ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE"
    },
    "errors": {}
}
```

When doing a `GET` to `https://localhost:433/users` with headers

```js
{
   Authorization: Bearer REMOVED
}
```

The `REMOVED` part above was the token returned from calling

```sh
curl 'http://localhost:3030/users/' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Here is my `default.json`

```js
{
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 433,
  "public": "../public/",
  "paginate": {
    "default": 10,
    "max": 50
  },
  "authentication": {
    "entity": "user",
    "service": "users",
    "secret": "REMOVED",
    "authStrategies": [
      "jwt",
      "local"
    ],
    "jwtOptions": {
      "header": {
        "typ": "access"
      },
      "audience": "http://vice-node-boilerplate",
      "issuer": "feathers",
      "algorithm": "RS256",
      "expiresIn": "1d"
    },
    "local": {
      "usernameField": "email",
      "passwordField": "password"
    },
    "oauth": {
      "redirect": "/",
      "auth0": {
        "key": "REMOVED",
        "secret": "REMOVED",
        "subdomain": "vicesoftware"
      }
    }
  },
  "postgres": "postgres://postgres:@localhost:5432/vice_node_boilerplate"
}
```

I've updated `authentication.js` as shown below

```js
const { AuthenticationService, JWTStrategy } = require('@feathersjs/authentication');
const { LocalStrategy } = require('@feathersjs/authentication-local');
const { expressOauth, OAuthStrategy } = require('@feathersjs/authentication-oauth');

class Auth0Strategy extends OAuthStrategy {
  async getEntityData(profile) {
    const baseData = await super.getEntityData(profile);

    return {
      ...baseData,
      email: profile.email
    };
  }
}

module.exports = app => {
  const authentication = new AuthenticationService(app);

  authentication.register('jwt', new JWTStrategy());
  authentication.register('local', new LocalStrategy());
  authentication.register('auth0', new Auth0Strategy());

  app.use('/authentication', authentication);
  app.configure(expressOauth());
};
```

and I've updated `index.js` as shown below

```js
/* eslint-disable no-console */
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const logger = require('./logger');
const app = require('./app');
const port = app.get('port');

const key = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/localhost-key.pem');
const cert = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/localhost.pem');

if (!key) {
  throw Error("Unable to read certificate key file");
}
if (!cert){
  throw Error("Unable to read certificate cert key file");
}

const server = https.createServer({
  key,
  cert
}, app).listen(port);

process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) =>
  logger.error('Unhandled Rejection at: Promise ', p, reason)
);

server.on('listening', () =>
  logger.info('Feathers application started on http://%s:%d', app.get('host'), port)
);
```

I generated the local dev cert files `localhost-key.pem` and `localhost.pem` following the instructions found here: https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/secure-local-development

**Edit 1**
Note that I also tried generating a cert using these instructions from node.js docs: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/

Comment: For RS256, did you make sure your cert is wrapped with "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" and "\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"?  That's the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You changed the `jwtOptions.algorithm` configuration to `RS256`. This needs additional configuration, specifically a valid private key. The error indicates that the private key provided is not valid. More information can be found in the [node-jsonwebtoken documentation](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken). I recommend to stick with the default `HS256/384/512` algorithms if you are not sure.